# Confusing Python Error

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am making a basic device using Python and I ran into this issue:

```
  File "/home/pi/Adafruit_Python_SSD1306/PyOS_V0.py", line 178, in <module>
gameMenuApp()
File "/home/pi/Adafruit_Python_SSD1306/PyOS_V0.py", line 92, in gameMenuApp
draw.text((0, 32), gameMenuText, font=StartupFinishFont,
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'gameMenuText' referenced before assignment
```

This doesn't make sense because I assigned the variable at the beginning the file. I also put the code into a python linter online but I did not receive an error. Also, I removed most of the code to try to make it easier to read so if something doesn't make sense, don't worry about it. I posted the code on Github as well. https://github.com/raspiuser6969/PyOS

```
gameMenuText = " "
gameMenuSelect = int(1)
gameMenu = ['   Pong    ','    RPS    ']
gameMenuSelect = int(1)
def pong():
def rps():
def gameMenuApp():
   while GPIO.input(A_pin):
        draw.rectangle((0,0,128,64), outline=0, fill=0)
        draw.text((0,32), gameMenuText, font=StartupFinishFont, fill=255)
        disp.image(image)
        disp.display()
        if not(GPIO.input(D_pin)):
            gameMenuSelect = gameMenuSelect + 1
            draw.rectangle((0,0,128,64), outline=0, fill=0)
            disp.image(image)
            disp.display()
            print(gameMenuSelect)
        if not(GPIO.input(U_pin)):
            gameMenuSelect = gameMenuSelect - 1
            draw.rectangle((0,0,128,64), outline=0, fill=0)
            disp.image(image)
            disp.display()
            print(gameMenuSelect)
        if gameMenuSelect == 1:
            gameMenuText = gameMenu[gameMenuSelect - 1]
            shutdownApp()
            time.sleep(0.1)
        if gameMenuSelect == 2:
            gameMenuText = gameMenu[gameMenuSelect - 1]
            rps()
            time.sleep(0.1)
        if 2 < gameMenuSelect:
            gameMenuSelect = gameMenuSelect - 1
        if 1 > gameMenuSelect:
            gameMenuSelect = gameMenuSelect + 1
```

Comment: You must declare it `global` with `global gameMenuText` at the beginning of your `gameMenuApp` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gameMenuText` is defined in your file, but not in your function. You should either pass it as argument:

```
def gameMenuApp(gameMenuText, gameMenuSelect, gameMenu, gameMenuSelect):
```

or use it as global:

```
def gameMenuApp():
    global gameMenuText, gameMenuSelect, gameMenu, gameMenuSelect
```

Same for your other globals, that's why I already added them.

Comment: Thank you! The global variable was the issue.